# Twilio Chat - Detect what is causing infinite and repetitive debug output

Tags: ios, chat, twilio

My debug logs are full of similar statements, triggering very fast (note the timestamps are just a couple hundreds of seconds apart) ad infinitum, and I can't figure out what is triggering it. I've added break points to all of my delegate methods I have.  Anybody know where I should look?

```
2017-08-02 14:52:33.653309-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[3]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.653 | INFO     | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /<SAME_TOKEN>/ size: 250
2017-08-02 14:52:33.654128-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[4]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.654 | DEBUG    | IPM | requesting sync list <SAME_TOKEN>
2017-08-02 14:52:33.656665-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[3]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.656 | INFO     | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /<SAME_TOKEN>/ size: 250
2017-08-02 14:52:33.657417-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[4]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.657 | DEBUG    | IPM | requesting sync list <SAME_TOKEN>
2017-08-02 14:52:33.659963-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[3]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.659 | INFO     | IPM | channels: got sync list token: /<SAME_TOKEN>/ size: 250
2017-08-02 14:52:33.660894-0400 APP[1028:108103] IPM[4]:        0x16ef3b000 | 08/02/14:52:33.660 | DEBUG    | IPM | requesting sync list <SAME_TOKEN>
```

I turned this output on using `[TwilioChatClient setLogLevel:TCHLogLevelDebug];`

I'm using the following delegate methods, with breakpoints at the beginning of all of them, none are hitting:

```
-(void)chatClient:(TwilioChatClient *)client connectionStateUpdated:(TCHClientConnectionState)state
-(void)chatClient:(TwilioChatClient *)client synchronizationStatusUpdated:(TCHClientSynchronizationStatus)status
-(void)chatClient:(TwilioChatClient *)client errorReceived:(TCHError *)error
-(void)chatClient:(TwilioChatClient *)client notificationNewMessageReceivedForChannelSid:(NSString *)channelSid messageIndex:(NSUInteger)messageIndex

-(void)accessManagerTokenExpired:(TwilioAccessManager *)accessManager
-(void)accessManagerTokenInvalid:(TwilioAccessManager *)accessManager
-(void)accessManagerTokenWillExpire:(TwilioAccessManager *)accessManager
```

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Those logs are just debug logs showing the internal workings of the SDK. You can turn them off again by setting the log level to a higher level, like `TCHLogLevelWarning`.

Comment: Thanks for hopping in. I know they're debug logs, but I'm only experiencing them when signed into a user that is unable to fully sync their twilio chat client, and it fires so rapidly that my simulator crashes after a couple minutes from running out of memory. I know I can turn them off, but it seems there's some sort of underlying issue causing them that I need to fix.

Comment: Ah, ok, it wasn't clear from your question that there was actually a problem with them. Can you update your post with an example of a access token that you've created for a user like this and how you set up the client with the token? Thanks!